# XML for Invoicing - Industry Standards?

Tags: xml, standards, dtd, invoices, cxml

I've come across an application that needs to send **invoice information** via FTP to various clients. The XML being output by the application is pretty simple however it does not conform to any particular standards (I imagine its home-grown).

Now a colleague has mentioned [**cXML**](http://www.cxml.org/) as a potential standard that we can use for invoice data and its widely available, however its a bit outdated as it uses DTD to validate the invoice data.

So basically I was wondering.: Do you know of any other standards that are currently in use for transmitting this type of information?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sadly, everyone makes up a new "standard" with every new project and technology.

Comment: As long as you are not enforced to, I don't see the need to comply with some standard just to follow the buzz du jour. The only driving forces you should consider are your requirements I think.

Comment: Hi mejaraz. Getting clients to pay invoices is hard enough as it is without convincing them to also adhere to a languge that they wont ever use with anyone else. While i agree with your desire to stay away from 'buzz de jour' in this case following a standard helps everyone in the long run.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [XML invoice specification - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497115/xml-invoice-specification), which has a bit more detail in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking into Universal Business Language (UBL).

http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=ubl

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, also doing a google search with cXML and UBL combined yielded some interesting results.